# Consulta com datadiff retornando 0 no resultado sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(hh, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA))AS HORAS
 FROM   ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW
WHERE  CHAPA = 3187 
  AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
  AND SEQUENCIALBATIDA IN (2,3) 

  GROUP BY DATA

ORDER BY DATA DESC
```

Exemplo:

```
HORAS
2
2
2
1
2
2
2
3
```

Só que ela só me retorna as horas,preciso dos outros campos que seria:

```
SELECT 
DATA,
CHAPA,
CODCOLIGADA,
BATIDA,
STATUS,
NATUREZA,
SEQUENCIALBATIDA,
DATEDIFF(hh, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA))AS HORAS
 FROM   ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW
WHERE  CHAPA = 3187 
  AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
  AND SEQUENCIALBATIDA IN (2,3) 

  GROUP BY DATA,CHAPA,CODCOLIGADA,BATIDA,STATUS,NATUREZA,SEQUENCIALBATIDA

ORDER BY DATA DESC
```

Mais quando rodo essa consulta com todos os campos o campo:   `DATEDIFF(hh, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA))AS HORAS` retorna com `0` 
Exemplo:

```
                                                                   HORAS
2016-10-17 00:00:00.000 123  1  2016-10-17 12:10:00.000 C   1   2   0
2016-10-17 00:00:00.000 123  1  2016-10-17 14:20:00.000 C   0   3   0
2016-10-14 00:00:00.000 123  1  2016-10-14 11:48:00.000 C   1   2   0
```

O que poderia ser ?

Qual meu interesse nesse campo hora,`listar resultados > 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso deve ocorrer porque `DATEDIFF` returna `INT`, e pode estar fazendo algum arredondamento.
Tente retornar em segundos e vai funcionar, veja o exemplo:

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime

set @d1='2016-10-19 15:40:52.847'
set @d2='2016-10-19 15:42:52.847'

-- Aqui retorna zero
select DATEDIFF(hh, @d1, @d2) AS HORAS

-- Aqui retorna certo, 2horas
select DATEDIFF(ss, @d1, @d2)/60 AS HORAS
```

No seu código:

```
DATEDIFF(ss, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA))/60 AS HORAS
```

Comment: Entendi e deu certo, Obrigado.